# Problema con assertEquals

Tags: java

Tengo problemas con unas pruebas que estoy pasando,concretamente con "assertEquals"

Realmente estoy comparando dos objetos de tipo "user" que tienen 3 parámetros "username,password,fullname"

En las pruebas hago esto:

```
    public void loginUser() {        
    Platform platform = new Platform();

    // Check that no user is in the platform
    assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 0);

    // Register new user
    User u1=platform.registerUser(username1, password1, fullName1);
    assertNotNull(u1);
    assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 1);

    // Try to login with the new user credentials
    User u2 = platform.login(username1, password1);
    assertNotNull(u2);
    assertEquals((int)platform.getNumUsers(), 1);

    // User information is correct
    assertEquals(u1, u2);
```

Primero compruebo que no existe ningún usuario,luego creo un usuario y por ultimo con el User u2 le paso el username y password de U1 y si la información de u1 y u2 es la misma sigo hacia adelante,el caso es que cuando llego al assertEquals(u1,u2) me dice que no son iguales pero yo creo que si lo son...

La clase donde hago los cálculos es esta la clase Platform

```
         package edu.uoc.dpoo;
         import java.util.ArrayList;
         import java.util.List;

      /**
        *
        * @author Guillermo Rodriguez Barcelo
        */
public class Platform {

private List<Competition> competitions;
private List<User> users;

public Platform(){

    competitions = new ArrayList<Competition>();
    users = new ArrayList<User>();

}
public User registerUser(String username ,String password,String fullname){

    User p = findUser(username);
    if (p == null) {
        p =  new User(username, password,fullname);
        users.add(p);
    }
    else {
        p=null;
    }

    return (User) p;
}



public User findUser (String username) {


           User user = null;

    for (User p : users) {
        if (username.equals(p.getUserName())) {
            user = p;
                            p= null;
            break;
        }
    }



    return user;
}


public User login(String username,String password){
    User user = null;

    for (User p : users){
        if(username.equals(p.getUserName())&& (password.equals(p.getPassword())) ){          
            user = p;
            break;
    }else
    {
            return null;
            }        
    }           
    return user;
}


public Integer getNumUsers(){
    Integer  size=users.size();

    return size  ;
}
public Integer getNumCompetitions(){
    return null;
}
public Message sendMessage(User from,String to,String subject,String message){
    return null;
}
private float evaluateAll(){
    return (float) 0.0;

}

public List<Competition> getOpenCompetitions(){
    return null;
}

private User User(User u) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}





}
```

El código de assertEquals es el siguiente

```
    static public void assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
    assertEquals(null, expected, actual);
}
```

El código del método assertEquals(null,expected,actual) es el siguiente

```
    static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected,
        Object actual) {
    if (equalsRegardingNull(expected, actual)) {
        return;
    } else if (expected instanceof String && actual instanceof String) {
        String cleanMessage = message == null ? "" : message;
        throw new ComparisonFailure(cleanMessage, (String) expected,
                (String) actual);
    } else {
        failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
    }
}



No entiendo por que me dice que los objetos u1 y u2 no son iguales.
```

Comment: Pon el código del método `assertEquals(int, int)` y `assertEquals(User, User)`

Comment: Edite la pregunta con el método assertEquals,no entiendo por que me da error si son iguales...

Comment: Añade el código del método `assertEqulas(null, expected, actual)` que estás usando en la última edición que hiciste. Además fíjate que éste método no informa que sean iguales porque no devuelve ningún resultado. O lo hace internamente en un código que no hemos visto o no hace nada.

Comment: Perdon,ya añadi el código del método assertEquals(null,expected,actual),sigo debugando pero no entiendo por que me falla

Answer (score 2):

Si mal no he entendido tu problema, creo que estás usando mal assertEquals. assertEquals, cuando lo usas con objetos, compara los objetos pero no los valores de los mismos. Es decir, dos objetos creados por separado, son dos objetos distintos.

Si quieres comprobar los valores tendrías que sobrescribir el método "equals" de tu clase e implementar tu propia lógica de comparación.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues bien,despues de dar muchas vueltas lo que hice fue esto

```
    @Override
public boolean equals (Object o) {
    boolean prueba = false;

    if ((o != null) && (o instanceof User)) {
        User p = (User) o;
        if (this.username == null && this.password == null && this.fullName == null) {
            prueba = (p.username == null);
                            prueba = (p.password == null);
                            prueba = (p.fullName == null);
        }
        else {
            prueba =  this.username.equals(p.username);
                            prueba =  this.password.equals(p.password);
                            prueba =  this.fullName.equals(p.fullName);
        }
    }

    return prueba;
}
```

Comparando parámetro a parámetro de cada objeto y asi me funciono...

Comment: Es que eso es básicamente lo que hay que hacer. Has estado dando vueltas con un montón de métodos que llaman a otros métodos que al final no devuelven nada. Me alegro que lo hayas solucionado al fin.